# Do sectors pay for synthetic upkeep?

Tags: stellaris

If I build synthetics/droids/robots in sectors, who pays for their energy upkeep, player or the sector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sector, it pays for everything in it with the exception of strategic resources.

Comment: It pays for the strategic resources as well.

Comment: @DcShannon Can't be, strategic resources are always added to my total, even if it they are in a sector. I've also never seen a sector build something requiring a resource.

Comment: If a sector needs a strategic resource that is in another sector, it is not available. If it needs one that it has in its own sector, then it uses it. I think it can use ones in your core sector as well, but I haven't actually tried that.

Comment: @DCShannon No, it will not. If its not in the sector, it doesn't exist (as far as the Sector's concerned)

Comment: As an added note, Sectors also ignore influence costs (such as building Planetary Administration/Capital).